# "DRY up" MVC models when using SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dry

I have just started MVC and i am able to find examples of most DRY principles online. Although I don't employ all as i find some make code a lot harder to read.

I have found one I cannot find an example of though and I feel like there must be a way to do it.

Basically at the moment I populate model selectlist type objects in the controller, this means I have to reuse the code. I know I could just put this in a method but I was wondering if there anyway to put it in the model so that anytime the model/viewmodel is used this action is called to populate the the selectlist contents.

I have put an example of my code below.

***Model***

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyWebsite.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    namespace CustomerWebsites.Models
    {
        public class CustomerWebsites
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
            public string WebsiteAddress { get; set; }
            public string WebsiteType { get; set; }
            public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public decimal Budget { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
            public string DevelopmentStatus { get; set; }
            public int CompletedPercentage { get; set; }
            public bool Completed { get; set; }
            public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
            public decimal TotalPaid { get; set; }

        }

        public class CustomerWebsitesDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public CustomerWebsitesDBContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

            public static CustomerWebsitesDBContext Create()
            {
                return new CustomerWebsitesDBContext();
            }
            public DbSet<CustomerWebsites> CustomerWebsites { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

***ViewModel***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyWebsite.ViewModels
{
    public class CreateCustomerWebsites
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string WebsiteAddress { get; set; }
        public string WebsiteType { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Budget { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string DevelopmentStatus { get; set; }
        public int CompletedPercentage { get; set; }
        public bool Completed { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPaid { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllUsers { get; set; }

    }

}
```

***Controler***

```
// GET: CustomerWebsites/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var users = db.Users.ToArray();

            var allUsers = users.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id,
                Text = x.Email
            });
            var model = new CreateCustomerWebsites
            {
                AllUsers = allUsers
            };

           return View(model);
        }

        // POST: CustomerWebsites/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateCustomerWebsites model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userGuid = new Guid(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                var developmentStatus = "Pending MyWebsite Review";

                if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                {
                    userGuid = model.UserGuid;
                    developmentStatus = model.DevelopmentStatus;
                } 


                db.CustomerWebsites.Add(new CustomerWebsites
                {
                    UserGuid = userGuid,
                    WebsiteAddress = model.WebsiteAddress,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ReleaseDate = model.ReleaseDate,
                    Budget = model.Budget ,
                    Description = model.Description,
                    DevelopmentStatus = developmentStatus,
                    CompletedPercentage = model.CompletedPercentage,
                    Completed = model.Completed,
                    TotalCost = model.TotalCost,
                    TotalPaid = model.TotalPaid
                });
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            var dbUsers = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var users = dbUsers.Users.ToArray();

            var allUsers = users.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id,
                Text = x.Email
            });
            model = new CreateCustomerWebsites
            {
                AllUsers = allUsers
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

***View***

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CustomerWebsites</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGuid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserGuid, Model.AllUsers, "-- Select a user --")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGuid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
       }

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WebsiteAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WebsiteAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WebsiteAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WebsiteType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WebsiteType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WebsiteType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { rows = "10", @class = "form-control"  })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DevelopmentStatus, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DevelopmentStatus, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DevelopmentStatus, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompletedPercentage, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompletedPercentage, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompletedPercentage, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Completed, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Completed)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Completed, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalCost, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalCost, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalCost, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalPaid, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalPaid, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalPaid, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Budget, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Budget, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Budget, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to post all that code when all your asking is about one property.

Comment: Does it really harm anyone if i do? You do have the choice not to read it if you feel lazy. Anyway, Since when was providing more information bad when it come to finding i possible solution? Also your post is what most people call spam, please refraim from anymore on this question thank you @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, it doesn't do any harm, but you are more likely to get good answers from a wide range of users if you follow the guidelines, particularly [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically at the moment I populate model selectlist type objects in
>   the controller, this means I have to reuse the code. I know I could
>   just put this in a method but I was wondering if there anyway to put
>   it in the model so that anytime the model/viewmodel is used this
>   action is called to populate the the selectlist contents.

It is generally not a good idea to put any methods in your viewmodels, especially for data access & population. Viewmodels should be plain data containers, void of knowledge or behavior. You are doing the right thing by populating the SelectList from the controller action.

As far as DRY, it looks pretty DRY to me already. You are only repeating one or two lines of code. You could DRY it up a little more by using something like AutoMapper to do the projection for you:

```
var users = dbUsers.Users.ToArray();
model = new CreateCustomerWebsites
{
    AllUsers = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(users)
};
```

...but do do this, you would have to add even more code to define the mapping. You could also like you mentioned in your question move the projection to a private method on the controller, but this would also mean adding more code, and would move some relevant code away from the controller action body. And you're effectively only removing 2 lines of code (one from each action that needs to hydrate the dropdown). Personally, I don't really see a problem with the way you are doing it now.

Another option could be to write an `ActionFilterAttribute` to populate the SelectList during `ResultExecuted`. But the point is, don't do it from the ViewModel: do it during the action execution.

Comment: Well that's good new I suppose. I just wanted to make sure i was doing it correctly. I have no experience with mapping as of yet. Am still unsure of what it is but I will look into it as it may come in handy for DRYing up code when its a lot more than the 2 lines i have on this one ha. Thanks so much

Comment: @DeveloperDevine The automapper tool is popular for those who often map from different objects. It basically lets you encapsulate `.Select(x => ...)` statements. I also have an open source project in my github account called AutoAutoMapper that helps with defining the mappings. Check it out if you ever end up using AutoMapper: https://github.com/danludwig/AutoAutoMapper

Comment: Methods are okay in viewmodels as long as they don't try to manipulate state. Methods to format data or get pieces of data are pretty common. Maybe that's what you meant.

Comment: @Shoe yes that is what I meant, sorry if there was any confusion. Get-only properties with a method body are OK in viewmodels too, but only when they are functional over existing state of the object and don't mutate state or have any other side effects.

Answer (score 0):

This might be OTT for your needs, but I looked at this a while ago and was also trying to address the fact that a db lookup was performed every time the selectlist was populated.

I have a service class that sits between the Controllers and dbcontext, so in your example I would have a class called `UserService.cs`.  The service class handles business logic & keeps the controller methods reasonably 'thin'. In the UserService class you have a method called `GetAsSelectList()`:

```
public SelectList GetAsSelectList()
{
    var b = CacheHelper.GetCacheItem("UserSelectList", UsersDelegate, CacheHelper.SlidingParam, CacheHelper.AbsoluteParam);
    return new SelectList((IEnumerable)b, "Id", "Name");
 }
```

This uses a CacheHelper class to check if the selectlist exists in memory.  If it does then it returns it, thus saving a database lookup.  If not in the cache, it runs the method below to generate the selectlist & store it in the cache with the name 'UserSelectList'.

```
private object UsersDelegate()
{
     return (from c in _context.Set<Users>()
             select new
             {
                c.Id, c.Name
             }).ToList();
}
```

The actual `CacheHelper` class can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/186fa44ab32df7052f78.git)

Using this approach has saved me loads of database lookups as I'm populating forms with multiple selectlists containing data that rarely - if ever - changes.